# Splash screen in Pysimplegui

Tags: splash-screen, pysimplegui

I tried using popup_animated but sometimes the image I use for splash screen doesn't load instead I see blank splash screen...is there another way to overcome this, below is code:

```
sg.popup_animated(r'.\Splash.gif')
time.sleep(3)
sg.popup_animated(None)
```

is there somethin different I need to do or is there another function I case use. thanks

Comment: `sg.popup_animated(r'.\Splash.gif')` just show one frame, refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Animated_GIFs.py

Comment: Thanks Jason, works now everytime using: for i in range(2000):
    if not sg.popup_animated(r'.\Splash.gif', no_titlebar=True):
        break
sg.popup_animated(None)